# React component not updating using redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to create a very simple Project in React to learn Redux, and I'm expecting that, whenever I click a button, the text inside a paragraph will be rendered, however, I can't get the app component (the only one I have) to get updated. Where am i failing?.

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'

const deleteUsers = 'delete users';

const createUser = 'créate user';

const createUserStranger = 'create stranger';

function deleteUsersActionCreator() {
  return {
    type: deleteUsers,
    data: []
  }
}

function createUsersActionCreator() {
  return {
    type: createUser,
    data: ['Irina', 'Denis', 'Julio']
  }
}

function createUserStrangerActionCreator() {
  return {
    type: createUserStranger,
    data: 'stranger'
  }
}

const initialState = {
  users: []
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case createUser:
      return {
        ...state,
        users: [...state.users, ...action.data]

      }
    case deleteUsers:
      return {
        ...state,
        users: []
      }
    case createUserStranger:
      return {
        ...state,
        users: [...state.users, action.data]
      }
      default:
        return state
  }
};

function dispatchAction(action) {
  store.dispatch(action)
}
const store = createStore(reducer);

let users = [];
store.subscribe(() => {
  users = store.getState().users
  console.log('users', users)

});


const App = () => {
  console.log(store.getState().users.map(e => e));
  console.log('rendering again')

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>People App </h1>
      <hr/>
      <p>
      {
        store.getState().users.map( user => {
          return 
          (<p>{user}</p>)
        })
      }
      </p>
      <button onClick={()=> dispatchAction(createUsersActionCreator())}>Add Family</button>
      <button onClick={()=> dispatchAction(createUserStrangerActionCreator())}>Add Stranger</button>
      <button onClick={()=> dispatchAction(deleteUsersActionCreator())}>Delete users</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

I know I should be using useState, usteEffect and this approaches, but since I'm learning react from zero, I thought it was a Good idea to learn redux as well. I've also Heard about Zustand (which I'm gonna learn too) but I'd like to have a Good grasp of raw redux. Any advise is very Good welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using React - better to use Hooks `useSelector` and `useDispatch` inside components

```
const App = () => {
  const users = useSelector(state => state.users)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  console.log('rendering again', users)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>People App </h1>
      <hr/>
      <p>
      {
        users.map( user => {
          return 
          (<p>{user}</p>)
        })
      }
      </p>
      <button onClick={()=> dispatch(createUsersActionCreator())}>Add Family</button>
      <button onClick={()=> dispatch(createUserStrangerActionCreator())}>Add Stranger</button>
      <button onClick={()=> dispatch(deleteUsersActionCreator())}>Delete users</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```